# Как переключиться на модальное окно и передать логин и пароль?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

На сайте есть кнопка "Войти". По нажатию на неё открывается всплывающая форма авторизации, на которую нужно переключиться:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И передать логин и пароль в неё. Как это сделать?

Содержит два поля:

```html
<input type="text" class="input">
<input type="password" class="input">
```

Comment: содержит два поля <input type ="text" class= "input">

Comment: <input type ="password" class= "input">

Comment: Если что, Вы можете дополнять свой вопрос, нажимая кнопку [edit] под ним.